# How to exclude specific columns from getDataRange()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using a script another user had written to combine all items in a google sheet together that are identical and use a delimiter (,) to separate them while being in the same cell. This script uses getDatarange  and I was hoping to find a way to utilize the script while excluding column B from having its identical values delimited together (but still have all other columns be added together with a delimiter) As an example of what I have tried below:

```
function mergeIdenticals() 
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sht.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, sht.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1, sht.getLastColumn() - firstCol + 1).sort(1);
  sht.appendRow(['***','***','Control-z one more time','***','***']); //need a throwaway row to get last data element out since I'm moving out    element[i-1]
  var datR = sht.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = sht.getRange("B:B").getLastRow(); //originally datR.getLastRow
  var lastCol = sht.getRange("B:B").getLastColumn(); // originally datR.getLastColumn
  var datA = datR.getValues();
  sht.getRange(2,2,lastRow - firstRow + 1,lastCol - firstCol + 1).clearContent().setWrap(true);
  var datoutA = [];
  var k=1;
  var n = 0;
  for(var i = 0;i < datA.length; i++)
  {
    if(i > 1)
    {
      if(datA[i][0] == datA[i-1][0])
      {
        k++;  //k is the number of consecutive matching values
      }
      else
      {
        datoutA[n] = [];
        if(k == 1)
        {
          // if k = 1 the datA[i-1] row gets copied into output array
          for(var c = 0;c < datA[i-1].length; c++)
          {
            datoutA[n][c]=datA[i-1][c];
          }
        }
        else
        {
          //i-1 to i-k rows get merged and copied into output array
          var firstTime = true;
          for(var a = 1;a <= k;a++)//input rows
          {            
            for(var b = 0;b < datA[i].length -1;b++)//input columns
            {
                if(a > 1 || b > 0) //no delimiter for first row or first column 
                {
                  datoutA[n][b] += ', ';
                }
               if(firstTime || b == 0)// straight assignment for first row and running sum after that same with first column because we only want   one of them because they're all the same.
               {
                 datoutA[n][b] = datA[i - a][b];
               }
               else
               {
                 datoutA[n][b] += datA[i - a][b];
               }
            }
            if(firstTime)//first assignment then running sums for last column
            {
              datoutA[n][datA[i].length - 1] = Number(datA[i - a][datA[i].length-1]);
            }
            else
            {
              datoutA[n][datA[i].length - 1] += Number(datA[i - a][datA[i].length-1]);
            }

            firstTime=false;
          }
          var end = 'is near';
        }
        k=1; //consecutive counter
        n++; //datoutA index 
      }

    }
 var datoutR = sht.getRange(2, 1, datoutA.length , datoutA[0].length);
  datoutR.setValues(datoutA);
  var colwidth = 250;
  sht.setColumnWidth(2, colwidth);
  sht.setColumnWidth(3, colwidth);
  sht.setColumnWidth(4, colwidth);
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Attempting to have all identical values be added to the same cells together and delimited, but excluding all values in column B (leaving only 1 value to each cell in column B with no delimiters/additional values.

Comment: You don't show what your are doing with dataoutA that matters what is in column B.

Comment: Can you share some sample data with the desired output? - probably there's another approach to solve your question.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I  added the final part of DataoutA  to the very bottom of the code (firing outside of all the for loops)


Attached is 2 screenshots. one of the data before any code is run. Column A has the title, column B is the name or description of the item and Column C is the quantity sold..  in column B all the different descriptions get delimited because there column A is the same. I can separate and add together all of column C in a formula but I can't separate the data in B once it gets merged.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nVzM9nLZPgyBt99gHcNuWK97s5QMXtYp/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LjfAEqjDYMIbCjLxl7-S4v6YYFTME20X/view?usp=sharing

Screenshot 2 (After the code is run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude Columns

```
function excludeCols() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let o = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(([a,,c,d,,f,g,,,,k]) =>[a,c,d,f,g,k]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  sh2.clearContents();
  sh2.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 | H2 | I2 | J2 | K2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 | H3 | I3 | J3 | K3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 | H4 | I4 | J4 | K4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 | F5 | G5 | H5 | I5 | J5 | K5 |
| 6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | I6 | J6 | K6 |
| 7 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | I7 | J7 | K7 |
| 8 | A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | G8 | H8 | I8 | J8 | K8 |
| 9 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | G9 | H9 | I9 | J9 | K9 |
| 10 | A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 | F10 | G10 | H10 | I10 | J10 | K10 |
| 11 | A11 | B11 | C11 | D11 | E11 | F11 | G11 | H11 | I11 | J11 | K11 |
| 12 | A12 | B12 | C12 | D12 | E12 | F12 | G |  |  |  |  |

Sheet2:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL3 | COL4 | COL6 | COL7 | COL11 |
| 2 | A2 | C2 | D2 | F2 | G2 | K2 |
| 3 | A3 | C3 | D3 | F3 | G3 | K3 |
| 4 | A4 | C4 | D4 | F4 | G4 | K4 |
| 5 | A5 | C5 | D5 | F5 | G5 | K5 |
| 6 | A6 | C6 | D6 | F6 | G6 | K6 |
| 7 | A7 | C7 | D7 | F7 | G7 | K7 |
| 8 | A8 | C8 | D8 | F8 | G8 | K8 |
| 9 | A9 | C9 | D9 | F9 | G9 | K9 |
| 10 | A10 | C10 | D10 | F10 | G10 | K10 |
| 11 | A11 | C11 | D11 | F11 | G11 | K11 |
| 12 | A12 | C12 | D12 | F12 | G12 | K12 |

Comment: Wow thats amazing! I will give this a go as soon as I can. Thank you for the thoughtful response!

Comment: After doing some testing  it seems to be working via deleting column B once it counts and delimits the quantities together. Thank you for the answer, Cooper!

Comment: Keep in mind it's not  deleting any of the columns it's selecting the ones you want and putting them in another array in any order that you wish.